# How to insert HTML break into magento product name

Tags: magento-1.9

Looking to find a way to make a line break e.g `<br />` on a product name.

I want the Manufacture name to site above the model. 
[image]

Comment: there is no difference between names in your question.

Comment: You should add more details to the question and clarify your problem a little more than this. In it's current form, it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Just so i understand you have a product name of `Manufacture Model Awesomeness` and you want to do the following: `Manufacture <br /> Model Awesomeness` on a product page?

Comment: Sorry about lack of details in original post. It was a late night.. 
See updated post with photo. 
Photo on the left is how it currently looks, photo on the right is how I want the product name to look.

Comment: You can increase the font size of the product title so that LK-9370 goes onto a different line.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162722)

Answer (score 3):

Try to print out a product name after replacing the first whitespace character with `<br />`:

```
$productName = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
echo preg_replace('/\s{1}/u', '<br/>', $productName, 1);
```

Default template located here: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

Change at lines ~55 & ~96:

```
<h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
```

to

```
<h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo preg_replace('/\s{1}/u', '<br/>', $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'), 1); ?></a></h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do the same so I used [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

I've added ' - ' (space dash space) in all the product titles I wanted my line break (You can use ' --- ' if you're using the ' - ' with other titles)

Then I've looked for

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
```

in list.phtml & list_featured_slider.phtml and I replaced it with

```
<?php 
   $productname = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
   $newproductname = str_replace(' - ', '<br />', $productname);

echo $newproductname 
?>
```

Worked for me just fine ;)

You can do it in view.phtml as well if you need the line break on product page

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your hints, here my working solution to replace "-" with < br> in the product title (category view = app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml):

```
<strong class="product name product-item-name">
      <a class="product-item-link" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
      <?php echo str_replace(' - ', '<br />', $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name')); ?></a>
</strong>
```

RESULT:

previous
POLO RALPH LAUREN Uomo - Giacca leggera antivento in nylon blu

now
 
POLO RALPH LAUREN Uomo 
Giacca leggera antivento in nylon blu